# String escaping issue with Roslyn statement creation

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've the following code, which builds up a Roslyn statement which calls Roslyn code inside, but I've a problem with string escaping.

Here is the code:

```
        var parseStatementArgument = "var statement = Syntax.ParseStatement(\\\"Console.WriteLine (\\\"Hello {0}\\\", parameter1);\\\");";

        var st = Syntax.InvocationExpression(
                                    Syntax.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.MemberAccessExpression, Syntax.IdentifierName("Syntax"), Syntax.IdentifierName("ParseStatement")))
                                        .AddArgumentListArguments(
                                            Syntax.Argument(Syntax.LiteralExpression(
                                                SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                                                Syntax.Literal(
                                                    text: "\"" + parseStatementArgument + "\"",
                                                    value: parseStatementArgument)
                                    )));

        var variableDeclarator = Syntax.VariableDeclarator(Syntax.Identifier("statement"))
            .WithInitializer(Syntax.EqualsValueClause(st));

        var varStatement = Syntax.VariableDeclaration(Syntax.IdentifierName("var"), Syntax.SeparatedList(variableDeclarator));

        var varStatementText = varStatement.Format().GetFormattedRoot().GetFullText() + ";";

        var scriptEngine = new ScriptEngine(
            new [] {
                MetadataReference.Create("Roslyn.Compilers"),
                MetadataReference.Create("Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp"),
                MetadataReference.Create("Roslyn.Services"),
                MetadataReference.Create("Roslyn.Services.CSharp")
            },
            new [] {
                "System",
                "Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp",
                "Roslyn.Scripting",
                "Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp",
                "Roslyn.Services"
            });

        var session = Session.Create();

        scriptEngine.Execute(varStatementText, session);

        scriptEngine.Execute("Console.WriteLine (statement.Format().GetFormattedRoot().GetFullText());", session);
```

The problem is that the "statement" printed to the console windows via the script engine execution will miss the backslashed around the "Hello {0}" string. If I add double escaping (additional \ into the parameter, Roslyn will raise compile errors about missing commas.

How may I update this code to get a syntactically correct version of what I want into the statement variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about switching to using verbatim string levels, and just add another level of escaping as you add the node.

Something like:

```
    var parseStatementArgument = @"var statement = Syntax.ParseStatement(@""Console.WriteLine (""""Hello {0}"""", parameter1);"");";
    var st = Syntax.InvocationExpression(
                                Syntax.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.MemberAccessExpression, Syntax.IdentifierName("Syntax"), Syntax.IdentifierName("ParseStatement")))
                                    .AddArgumentListArguments(
                                        Syntax.Argument(Syntax.LiteralExpression(
                                            SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                                            Syntax.Literal(
                                                text: "@\"" + parseStatementArgument.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"",
                                                value: parseStatementArgument)
                                )));
```

Comment: No, what I try to achieve is to construct the same statement, but its just a twist, it can be any other var x = Syntax.ParseStatement ("..."); code.

Comment: Then you get this error, what I mentioned:

Unhandled Exception: Roslyn.Compilers.CompilationErrorException: (1,80): error C
S1003: Syntax error, ',' expected.

Comment: Something went wrong during the copy/paste when I tested your solution, since now it ran correctly :-(
So this verbatim syntax can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kevin's tip on how to replace string for literals I played around and found this as a solution that works, but it raised another problem.

The solution:

```
        var parseStatementArgument = "var statement = Syntax.ParseStatement(\\\"Console.WriteLine (\\\\\\\"Hello {0}\\\\\\\", parameter1);\\\");";

        var st = Syntax.InvocationExpression(
                                    Syntax.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.MemberAccessExpression, Syntax.IdentifierName("Syntax"), Syntax.IdentifierName("ParseStatement")))
                                        .AddArgumentListArguments(
                                            Syntax.Argument(Syntax.LiteralExpression(
                                                SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                                                Syntax.Literal(
                                                    text: "\"" + parseStatementArgument + "\"",
                                                    value: parseStatementArgument.Replace ("\\\\\\", "\\"))
                                    )));
```

Now it correctly outputs a code snippet which is syntactically correct and compiles well.

The problem it raises is that I had to modify the source string and not the derived string to get the correct result. When rewriting code or generating code with Roslyn it can not be a requirement to double or triple escape string literals to make Roslyn able to deal with that correctly, maybe its a Roslyn issue, I hope that someone will shed some light on an elegant solution which works for all kind of strings.

Comment: Well, this is a bit of an esoteric case - where you are trying to create Parse statements that you then feed into execute.  Why not just parse the entire original input, transform it, to string it and then Execute that?  Why add the extra indirection of building up statements that do the parsing?

Comment: Execute is just an additional step I added, the full building is required as we talked about before, to be able to build code which builds Roslyn code. So the statement what I pass into the script engine can be either executed OR just pasted into a method. If you use this kind of stuff during a DSL transformation and doing the transform at runtime I think you need to execute the transformation without caring about the source code your built up during the transformation.